# Encoding strange persian csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, utf-8, decode

I want to read a CSV file that has some Persian(Farsi) text in it

what is the right encoder for it?

one of csv line is there:

```
9004090036,98,02,01,34028036 ,üَن,‎¤ّîھ,¢‏م¨,0520275950 ,يگ¤گ, 0 ,¢¤ُ ,ü÷گ¤‏گ ,ù¢‘¨ ¤ً¤‘î ,98/02/01
```

Comment: Start with UTF-8

Comment: @snakecharmerb i try to figure out what the encoding and finding this :charset=unknown-8bit

Comment: It looks like [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) - text that's been decoded using the wrong encoding.  Can you [edit] the question to include raw bytes?

Answer (score 2):

I convert the text file to hex and find out in is encode with 'iransystem' encoding scheme
[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iran_System_encoding)

Comment: Interesting problem. "iransystem" is pre Microsoft codepage but apparantly still in common use which means there are going to solutions out there. I found https://github.com/gmt3141/python-iransystem.git but no guarantees it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use google doc spreadsheet. Copy or import your table in google doc new spreadsheet and then download in CSV format. Open your CSV file with Notepad and save as with UTF-8 format. Now your CSV file is ok.